# Wrong number or types of arguments in to call to 'GET_ID_BRIEF'

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have been trying to call a stored procedure in oracle in my C# windows form using visual studio 2012. I am getting the following error : PLS-00306: Wrong number or types of arguments in to call to 'GET_ID_BRIEF'.
I checked for two days and made sure that all variables types and order are correct. I am using In my project more than 20 stored procedures and none of them had an execution problem. 
I also tried to execute this procedure in SQL Plus command shell, and got the correct results without any errors.

This is the Procedure :

```
create or replace procedure Get_ID_brief (IDp number, namep out varchar2, curr_pos out varchar2,hire_date out varchar2, morly out varchar2, pos_start out varchar2,done out boolean)
as
begin
    done:=true;
    select name, position, payment, startdate,hiredate
    into namep,curr_pos,morly,pos_start,hire_date
    from employees_brief
    where ID=IDp;

exception
    when no_data_found then done:=false;
end;
/
```

this is the error I am getting :

```
ORA-06550: line1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_ID_BRIEF'
ORA-06550: line1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

This is the C# code that generated this error :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = "DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/test;PASSWORD=onetwothree;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=C##kidzclub";

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "Get_ID_brief";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("IDp", OracleDbType.Int16);
        cmd.Parameters["IDp"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["IDp"].Value = id;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("namep", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        cmd.Parameters["namep"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("curr_pos", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        cmd.Parameters["curr_pos"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("hire_date", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        cmd.Parameters["hire_date"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("morly", OracleDbType.Boolean);
        cmd.Parameters["morly"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("pos_start", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        cmd.Parameters["pos_start"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("done", OracleDbType.Boolean);
        cmd.Parameters["done"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;





        try { cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
        catch (OracleException Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);

        }

        Boolean done = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.Parameters["done"].Value.ToString());
        if (done) MessageBox.Show("It Works");
        else MessageBox.Show("It did not work");



    }
```

this is the code of another function in my project that uses another procedure, I could not find any difference to execute such error :

```
private void Button_add_emp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fname = text_fname.Text;
        string lname = text_lname.Text;
        string pass = text_password.Text;
        string position = combo_positions.SelectedValue.ToString();
        int pos = Convert.ToInt16(position);
        string morly = combo_morly.Text;
        string hdate = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();
        label_new_emp.Text = hdate;
        bool result;
        label_new_emp.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        if (fname.Length == 0)                      {label_new_emp.Text = "Enter the first\nname to continue"; return ;}
        if (lname.Length == 0)                      {label_new_emp.Text = "Enter the last\nname to continue";  return ;}
        if (pass.Length == 0)                       {label_new_emp.Text = "Enter a password\n to continue";return ;}
        if (pass.Length < 8)                        { label_new_emp.Text = "Password must be\nmore than 8 characters"; return; }
        if (combo_positions.SelectedIndex == -1)    {label_new_emp.Text = "Choose a position\nto continue";return ;}
        if (combo_morly.SelectedIndex == -1)        {label_new_emp.Text = "Choose Monthly or\nHourly to continue";return ;}




        string constr = "DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/test;PASSWORD=onetwothree;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=C##kidzclub";

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);   
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "new_emp"; 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("first_namep", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        cmd.Parameters["first_namep"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["first_namep"].Value = fname;


        cmd.Parameters.Add("last_namep", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        cmd.Parameters["last_namep"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["last_namep"].Value = lname;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("position_IDp", OracleDbType.Int16);
        cmd.Parameters["position_IDp"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["position_IDp"].Value = pos;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("hire_datep", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        cmd.Parameters["hire_datep"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["hire_datep"].Value = hdate;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("monhourly", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        cmd.Parameters["monhourly"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["monhourly"].Value = morly;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("pass", OracleDbType.NVarchar2);
        cmd.Parameters["pass"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters["pass"].Value = pass;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("done", OracleDbType.Boolean);
        cmd.Parameters["done"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        result = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.Parameters["done"].Value.ToString());
        if (result) label_new_emp.Text = "Employee Added";
        else label_new_emp.Text = "An Error Occured,\n check for duplicate names";
    }
```

this is the view from where the procedure gets it outputs :

```
create or replace view employees_brief 
as 
    select e.ID,first_name||' '||last_name as name, p.name as position,j.hourly_monthly as Payment, to_char(start_date,'dd/mm/yy') as StartDate, to_char(hire_date,'dd/mm/yy') as HireDate
    from employees e, positions p, jobs j
    where e.position_ID=p.ID and e.ID=j.employee_ID;
```

This is How I tested My Procedure :

```
declare 
    namep  varchar2(25);
    curr_pos varchar2(25);
    hire_date varchar2(25);
    morly  boolean;
    pos_start varchar2(25);
    done  boolean;
begin 
    Get_ID_brief (1, namep , curr_pos ,hire_date, morly,pos_start,done );
    dbms_output.put_line(namep);
    dbms_output.put_line(curr_pos);
    dbms_output.put_line(hire_date);
    if(morly=true)then dbms_output.put_line('morly is true');
    else dbms_output.put_line('morly is false');end if;
    dbms_output.put_line(pos_start);
    if(done=true)then dbms_output.put_line('done is true');
    else dbms_output.put_line('done is false');end if;
end;
/
```

And this is the correct output that I got :

```
Admin Admin
Admin
01/08/14
morly is true
01/08/14
done is true

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Your "done out boolean" parameter is being mapped to a "OracleDbType.NVarchar2" in your first C# code - look closely at what it is mapped to in the 2nd. Not sure sure how well booleans are supported in ODP.net.

Comment: I fixed it, but still having exactly the same error :$

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099833/can-odp-net-pass-a-parameter-to-a-boolean-pl-sql-parameter

Comment: Thanks TenG, but I am using Boolean and I am not having any problems, I have been working for 2 weeks on the application , and did not encounter any problem until  this. I fixed another mistake that was done, when declaring morly as NVrachar2 in oracle, it also is Boolean. but now the error is : ORA-06502: Pl/SQL: numeric or value error. ORA-06512: at "C#KIDZCLUB.GET_ID_BRIEF", line 6. ORA-0512: at line 1. I update in my question how I tested the procedure in command prompt, and the results I got

Comment: You are also using Nvarchar2 for namep when the procuedre signature species varchar2.

Comment: Dear Ron, I fixed it to Varchar2, and it did not make a difference,I do not think this had to do with the error since in other functions I am using Nvarchar2 without any problem