# Can ODP.NET pass a boolean parameter type to stored procedure?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I am using ODP.NET 12.1.2400 and EF6 with an Oracle 11 database.

I have an Oracle stored procedure that has a parameter of type BOOLEAN. I have imported this stored procedure and added the function import to my EF data model. However I get a runtime exception:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDURE_NAME'

When I change the stored procedure parameter type to NUMBER and update the EF model, everything works correctly.

Is there a way to use the BOOLEAN type? Or at least use a bool parameter in the .NET code (without having to create wrapper functions for the EF function imports)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099833/can-odp-net-pass-a-parameter-to-a-boolean-pl-sql-parameter

Comment: @thinklarge Thanks, I did look at that thread but it hasn't been updated in two years and wasn't specifically using the EF data model. I was hoping there have been some improvements since then.

Comment: If I remember correctly, natively binding to BOOLEAN in stored procedures is only supported starting with Oracle Database 12c. Until that version you need to bind as a number.